# Setting connection retry limit of orientdb

Tags: java, orientdb

Hello I am using orientdb in distributed environment where there are two orientdb servers instances on say dbSrv-1 and dbSrv-2. I have followed the following [tutorial](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-Setup-a-distributed-database.html) to setup a distributed databases and it is working fine.

But the problem I am facing is when a node is down and java client tries to connect to that particular node, in such a case client seems to be stuck in an infinite loop of connection retries.
I have tried setting orientdb global setting via command line like this:

```
java -Dnetwork.retry=1
```

also tried setting it at runtime like this

```
OGlobalConfiguration.NETWORK_SOCKET_RETRY.setValue(1);
```

but nothing doesn't seem to work. Following is code to open a database connection:

```
db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/mydb").open("admin", "admin");
```

Java exception trace is below:

```
Oct 15, 2015 8:03:48 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
SEVERE: Can not open database with url localhost:2424/mydb
com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Cannot open a connection to remote server: localhost:2424/mydb
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.getAvailableNetwork(OStorageRemote.java:2114)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1841)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:222)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.open(OStorageRemoteThread.java:89)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:249)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPolled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:140)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:343)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:313)
        at com.worldhubcom.cc.mydb.db.DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:45)
        at com.worldhubcom.cc.mydb.db.SubscriberDao.save(SubscriberDao.java:35)
        at com.worldhubcom.cc.mydb.authen.ServiceAuthenticate.main(ServiceAuthenticate.java:24)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Error on connecting to localhost:2424/mydb
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager.createNetworkConnection(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:246)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager$1.createNewResource(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:80)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager$1.createNewResource(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:77)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getResource(OResourcePool.java:94)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager.acquire(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:101)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.getAvailableNetwork(OStorageRemote.java:2103)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.<init>(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:83)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager.createNetworkConnection(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:233)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Which release? Java client should switch automatically to the next available node. Could you share any logs of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Lvca i have added the exception and the orientdb-graphdb java client I am using is 2.1.0

Comment: Are you sure the 2 nodes are up & running? Could you attach the initial logs at startup?

Comment: I replaced 2.1.0 with 2.1.4 and it fixed the infinite loop issue. Yes there are two nodes up and running and they both see each other but the thing is my program makes db connection against each request, so in case if a node is down and my program tries to make a connection it fails. I m still not able to configure DNS and was trying to use multiple url stuff, but it doesnt work

Comment: You could also open a connection to a list of addresses. Look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration.html#use-multiple-addresses

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/test", "admin", "admin");
        OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
        OrientInsert.testInsertion(graph);
        graph.shutdown();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("End main");

    }

    public static class OrientInsert {

        public static void testInsertion(OrientGraphNoTx graph) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
            int count  = 1000;

            //create class 1
            OClass clVertice1;
            OrientVertex vVertice1;

            clVertice1 = graph.createVertexType("CLASS1", "V");
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop1", OType.STRING);
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop2", OType.STRING);
            clVertice1.createProperty("prop3", OType.STRING);


            //create class 2
            OClass clVertice2;
            OrientVertex vVertice2;

            clVertice2 = graph.createVertexType("CLASS2", "V");
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop1", OType.STRING);
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop2", OType.STRING);
            clVertice2.createProperty("prop3", OType.STRING);


            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("i :"+i+" -------------------" );
                //....class 1
                vVertice1 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS1");
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop1", Integer.toString(i));
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop2", "22"); 
                vVertice1.setProperties("prop3", "3333"); 

                for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                    System.out.print("");
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                    //...class 2
                    vVertice2 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS2");
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop1", Integer.toString(i + j / 1000));
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop2", "22"); 
                    vVertice2.setProperties("prop3", "3333"); 

                    //edge                  
                    graph.addEdge(null, vVertice1, vVertice2, "v1v2");

                }
            }
        }

}
```

The result is this (i selected only 2 vertex with limit 100 E):
[image]